# He is expected to address activists on the sidelines of the conference. (rephrase)

Tags: phrase-meaning

> He is expected to address activists on the sidelines of the conference.

What's the meaning of the sentence and how could it be rephrased especially the part "on the sidelines of the conference?

Comment: What do you already understand about this quote? Which part are you unsure about? Are there two meanings you think it could possibly have? Do you know what "on the sidelines" means? Have you looked up the word "sidelines"? Please show that you've made some effort

Comment: @gotube Already looked up the word.

Answer (score 1):

The problem here is that the meaning of the original sentence is unclear.

“Address” may mean “give a formal speech or presentation” or may mean “cope with a problem.”

“Sidelines” is a metaphor from sports; conferences do not literally have sidelines whereas football fields do. Absent context, it is impossible to know whether what is being referred to is the entrance to the building where the conference is held or an interior space reserved for observers.

Indeed even “activists” is a vague and possibly politically loaded word. It can cover anything from protestors peacefully exercising their rights of speech and assembly to violent thugs.

When people write vaguely, paraphrasing accurately is impossible.

Comment: What do you think 'on the sidelines' modifies? activists or address?

Comment: I think it is **intended** to denote the place where the activists are to be addressed. So, effectively, it modifies the entire sentence. It would make no sense to address them where they are not. So in the narrowest sense it specifies (vaguely) where the activists are. But that is a super-technical way to think about language. The sense is that the place where the activists are and where they are to be addressed is the same, and it is that place that is being indicated.

Comment: I guess the meaning is like: activists on the sidelines of the conference = activists who didn't particate in the conference and he is going to give a speech to them.

Comment: My whole point is that it is not a well-drafted senstnece: absent context, you do need to guess about what exactly is intended. Your guess is reasonable.